# In Rails how do I have a user click to share a specific image with specific text to Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm struggling with this bit of code. What I'd like is for when a user is looking at an image and they want to share it on Facebook they click on the Share option and click Facebook. Then Facebook opens up to share that image with the text that is defined for that image.

I've been working with the following:

```
<%= link_to ""http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}", target: :_blank do %>
        <%= image_tag("/specific image.jpg", class: :facebook_icon, alt: "Facebook") %>
      <% end %>
```

This clearly isn't working. I know I need to have a place to do the text. I've also tried:

```
<%= link_to "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}",  title: 'Share Me!' do %><i class="huge facebook icon" data-content="Share Me!">
<%= image_tag('specific image.jpg') %></i><% end %>
```

Which doesn't work. Really all I want on the dropdown is the Facebook icon. Then the link itself should carry that image with text. So shouldn't it be something like:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('/images/specific_image.jpg'), "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={url}", :target => "_blank", title: "Some text goes here for description" %>
```

But that's not right either because it's trying to display the image not sharing the image. Any feedback?

Comment: You need an individual URL for each individual piece of content that you want to share.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= asset_url('image.jpg') %>" target="_blank" title="Click to share on Facebook"><span></span>Click to share on Facebook (Opens in new window)</a>
```

This works but...doesn't offer adding in a caption.